# Different regex output on 2 PHP systems?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

Given this test script:

```
<?php

echo setlocale(LC_ALL, '') . "\n";

$in = 'Città';

$var = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $in);

echo bin2hex($in) . "\n";
echo bin2hex($var) . "\n";
```

PHP 5.5.3 on Ubuntu, I get:

```
en_GB.UTF-8
43697474c3a0
43697474c3a0
```

PHP 5.5.9 on Mac (via Macports)

```
en_GB.UTF-8
43697474c3a0
43697474c3
```

Is there any reason why the Macports build will be treating the `à` character differently?

I'm aware that `c3a0`, when treated as two bytes in ASCII, is `Ã` followed by a non-breaking space. I am wondering why one system treats the 2 bytes as UTF-8 without the `u` modifier.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use the `/u` modifier? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php The pattern would then be `/\s+$/u`

Comment: Using the u modifier results in the same output on both machines (which is what we used to fix the problem) but I am curious as to why the lack of a u modifier presents different results.

Comment: @TimJones With the `u` modifier, php/regex engine will treat the input as UTF-8 string. So with the `u` modifier it will "recognise" that `0xc3a0` is `à` while without the `u` modifier it will "recognise" them as separate characters `0xc3` and `0xa0`. `0xa0` is [some kind of space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), that's why it removes it since `\s` matches a whitespace.

Comment: @HamZa Yup, that's my understanding also. I am confused as to why the Ubuntu system is treating `0xc3a0` as a unicode character _without_ using the u modifier. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please check which version of libpcre PHP was linked against and what configuration was used for it. I always recommend to use the bundled version to avoid such issues. Probably PCRE was compiled with different locales.

Comment: @TimJones: A wild guess: Perhaps it has to do with different Unicode normalizations in Ubuntu and Mac? (NFC vs NFD)

Comment: You can know if the difference comes from locales (that are used to compile the pcre module) with a simple test. Try to match the `à` with `\w`.

Comment: If you set ``setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C')`` on Mac (some internal encoding?), then it will return same results (and, as Tim says, treat $in as unicode without the u modifier?)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE_UTF8) This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE
>   that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.

By default, the string is treated as a sequence of single-byte characters; the problem is that some of your characters are encoded as multibyte in UTF-8. While `0xc3a0` is a single codepoint, `\s` will match on its second byte, `0xa0`, which is a non-breaking space, and therefore whitespace.

```
$var = preg_replace('/\s+$/u', '', $in);
```

should enable UTF-8 mode for matching, and it should work on all systems.

Comment: `U+00A0` is a non-breaking space, not a linefeed (that would be `U+000A`),  but it's a whitespace character either way. +1

Comment: @AlanMoore: Oh, right - silly me. Thank you for the correction.